# Bayes Network Homework

Tags: bayesian-network

I have a homework due in 3 hours and absolutely no idea how to solve this :

[image]

To 1: 
$B$ can be either $0$ OR $1$ ..
$P(D=1| A=1) =  P(A=1) * ...$ 
(I have no idea what to put here)

To 2: 
$B$ and $C$ are independent. Therefore :
$P(B=0|C=0) = P(B=0) = 1-\alpha + 1-\beta$

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayes' Theorem? Seems like that would be useful for you to answer Part 1. Your answer to 2 seems correct, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, note that:
\begin{align*}
&\Pr(D = 1 \mid A = 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{\Pr(A = 1)} \Pr(A = 1, D = 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{\Pr(A = 1)} \sum_b \sum_c \Pr(A = 1, B = b, C = c, D = 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{\Pr(A = 1)} \sum_b \sum_c \Pr(A = 1)\Pr(B = b \mid A = 1)\Pr(C = c)\Pr(D = 1 \mid B = b, C = c) \\
&= \sum_b \Pr(B = b \mid A = 1)\sum_c \Pr(C = c)\Pr(D = 1 \mid B = b, C = c) \\
\end{align*}
Now just plug in the four possible pairs of $(b, c)$ to get your answer.

---

For the second question, note that you need to weight the two options according to $\Pr(A)$:
\begin{align*}
\Pr(B = 0 \mid C = 0)
&= \Pr(B = 0) \\
&= \sum_a \Pr(A = a, B = 0) \\
&= \sum_a \Pr(A = a)\Pr(B = 0 \mid A = a) \\
&= \Pr(A = 0)\Pr(B = 0 \mid A = 0) + \Pr(A = 1)\Pr(B = 0 \mid A = 1) \\
&= 0.3(1 - \beta) + 0.7(1 - \alpha) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: would it be : P(B=0 |A=1) * P(C=0) * P(D=1 | B=0,C=0) + 
P(B=1 |A=1) * P(C=0) * P(D=1 | B=1,C=0) +
P(B=0 |A=1) * P(C=1) * P(D=1 | B=0,C=1) +
P(B=1 |A=1) * P(C=1) * P(D=1 | B=1,C=1)

Comment: Yep, that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

For part 1: Naively I would say you could "replace" the terms in the table for D, so that B=1 becomes a and B=0 1-a, C=1 to g and C=0 is 1-g. And then it's just a matter of writing all terms for D=1 out without interpunction. P(D=1|A=1) = 0.4ag+0.2a(1-g)+0.7(1-a)g+0.5(1-a)(1-g)... Which you can simplify..